# Error Loading Class in Lambda function (Java)

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I am quite new to AWS service and I am trying to deploy Java Lambda function but I keep getting this error message,

```
{   
  "errorMessage": "Error loading class com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException",            
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"         
}
```

I export java project in eclipse to convert .jar file but I can't add external libraries with .jar file.

Thanks

Comment: This means the class is not on the class path. But you provided no other information to help specifically. Are you familiar with java or just trying to get it to work work?

Comment: I am new to Java. I am just trying to test AWS Lambda function. But I got this exception I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Basically your issue is that the Java Libraries that contain 'com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler' are not loaded into the Java Virtual Machine Class Path on launch and thus it is not finding the class definition. This error probably wont be solvable via a question here. Steps I would take to try and solve it, would by looking through the AWS documentation to see if there is FAQ or Support with others having the same issue and or how to fix/properly deploy any software required to get it to work. While this is a Java class/library it really is not an issue with Java the language.

Answer (score 0):

In the AWS Lambda Console, double check that the value in the "Handler" field matches (exactly) the package and classname of your Java class that will handle the requests.

If you are using CloudFormation to deploy this, then check the handler value in the CloudFormation yaml/json.

> Either package.class-name::handler or package.class-name.  For
>   example, "com.Hello::myHandler" would call the myHandler method
>   defined in Hello.java.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a jar that uses other libraries you'll have to use a .zip file, not a .jar file. To compile everything to a zip file, add a task like this one

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
from compileJava
from processResources
into('lib') {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
}
}
```

As shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html#java-package-gradle)